# How to keep iterating over data structure after inserting elements into it?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, llvm

In the code snippet below, I insert `Instruction`'s into the `BasicBlock` pointed to by `Function::iterator bs`. The inner loop iterates over the instructions contained within this `BasicBlock`.

Now, after the inner loop inserts these instructions, the program goes into an infinite loop with instruction sequence:

```
and
mul
xor
and
mul
xor
and
mul
xor
and
mul
xor
and
mul
xor
and
mul 
...
```

How would I insert into the data structure being iterated over, while avoiding going into an infinite loop?

Somehow the iterator goes nuts (or it is invalidated). Is there a common idiom for how to tackle this problem?

```
for (Function::iterator bs = F.begin(), be = F.end(); bs != be; ++bs) {
    for (BasicBlock::iterator is = bs->begin(), ie = be->end(); is != ie; ++is) {
        Instruction& inst  = *is;
        BinaryOperator* binop = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&inst);

        if (!binop) {
            continue;
        }

        unsigned opcode = binop->getOpcode();
        errs() << binop->getOpcodeName() << "\n";

        if (opcode != Instruction::Add) {
            continue;
        }

        IRBuilder<> builder(binop);
        Value* v = builder.CreateAdd(builder.CreateXor(binop->getOperand(0), binop->getOperand(1)), 
                                     builder.CreateMul(ConstantInt::get(binop->getType(), 2), 
                                                       builder.CreateAnd(binop->getOperand(0), binop->getOperand(1))));

        ReplaceInstWithValue(bs->getInstList(), is, v); // THINGS GO WRONG HERE!
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'd just create a new list, and append to it instead of modifying the collection you're iterating over. A map/filter combo should work too.

Comment: What does `ReplaceInstWithValue` look like?

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/BasicBlockUtils_8cpp_source.html#l00189

Comment: Surely, if you add elements to a container you cannot also cache the end iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you failed to provide sufficient details, but I strongly suspect that you're inserting a new element into a container in such a way that existing iterators (to other elements) are invalidated. This is the usual behaviour for many container classes, e.g. [`std::vector<>::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), which invalidates all existing iterators if the new `size()` exceeds `capacity()` (otherwise only existing iterators to elements before the insertion point remain valid).

The way to avoid this is to use a container that does not suffer from this problem, e.g. a `std::list<>`, since [`std::list<>::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) does not invalidate any existing iterator or reference.

Comment: So how would you tackle this problem?